# Spring Security. При авторизации вылетает ошибка Method Not Allowed

Tags: spring, spring-security, config, login

решил добавить авторизацию при помощи Security. Весь код брал отсюда - https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/.
Добавил в конфигурационный файл автоматическое создание контроллера для авторизации:

```
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
```

Добавил конфиг файл для Security:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

И добавил страницу login:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Однако, при вводе юзера и пароля - вылетает ошибка 405 Method Not Allowed(Request method 'POST' not supported). Что можно сделать? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: у вас там солянка. В ней придется разобраться чуток. (плюс у меня отдельностоящего сервера приложений сейчас под рукой нет). Поэтому я после 5 смогу точно помочь. быстрее не получится –

Comment: @Михаил Ребров, да, солянка лютая, я только только начал разбираться. Без проблем, буду ждать, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфигурациях и коде все вроде верно на первый взгляд.

Единственное, что могу предположить:

Добавьте аннотацию `@Configuration` над `WebSecurityConfig`, чтобы Spring не забыл все это дело обработать.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Добавил, ошибка не пропала

Comment: @Temik, можете проект выложить в github и ссылочку дать чтобы можно было быстрее просмотреть что там еще может быть?

Comment: https://github.com/Temik-Karpov/AccountingOfWorkingHours @Михаил Ребров